# Comparing cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two cells which are both formatted the same.

The code is in a For loop:

```vb
If SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value <> SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value Then
    result = False
End If
```

I tried converting the values to doubles, but my macro sees them as different even though the values are identical.

When I debug the code, the values in the immediate window are the same:

```
? SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value  
 310289286,463803

? SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value  
 310289286,463803
```

Comment: You say they are formatted the same, does that mean that the values are different, but you are formatting them (rounding them) to a certain amount of digits? hmm i re-read it and i guess not. My thought was, trying to use the `.Text` property instead of `.Value` - worth testing at least.

Comment: Is it possible that one is formatted as a number, but the other is formatted as text? That would make them not equal, but appear equal in the debug window.

Comment: If the compared values result from some calculations,  it is possible that they really are not identic, even if they look so for your eyes. I would try `If Round(SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value, 6) <> Round(SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value, 6) Then`. Of course, if both of them have the same format...

Comment: i just wanted to eliminate the posibility that excel finds the values different because one is text and one is number, but no, they are both identical numbers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions until now. i will try to use .text and to round them, see where it gets me

Comment: Did you try my above suggestion (to identically round the numbers)?

Comment: see vba operators - https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-operators/

Comment: Have you tried to subtract one number from the other and display the output? Possibly further multiply the output by something like 10^20.

Comment: ok, maybe o got lazy and didn't try to test the substraction, but you guys are right:
? SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value - SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
 1,78813934326172E-07

but compared in the spreadsheet and not in vba, the results is always true, which is really weird

Comment: Not weird. It is a well documented consequence of using the IEEE standard for storing floats as double-precision binary, something almost all spreadsheet programs do.

Comment: What about `Val(SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value) <> Val(SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld had no idea, actually. will read into it, thanks!

Comment: I should have written *storing double precision floating point numbers as binary*. And you might take a look at [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result), but there are plenty of similar articles.

Answer (score 0):

If `result` has been defined as a boolean variable, the default value will be false. So unless there is another part of the code where `result` is set to true, It wil always return false.

Maybe try something like this:

```
If SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value = SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value Then
    result = True
End If
```

Comment: A better way to get around this is to eliminate the default state entirely, by assigning the boolean result of the comparison to `result` directly and removing the `if` statement: `result = SomeSheet.Cells(i, col).Value = SomeOtherSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value`.